# Apache2 host, url not served with mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache, ubuntu, mod-wsgi

Just stated to host a website with Django, the problem is like this.

I put an html file for testing under `/usr/local/django/virenv/Personal/mysite.com/`, which is also the Document root in `000-default.conf`, that page can be access via mysite.com

Then I started a django project and an app, in the app/view.py I put

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse    
def index(request):
        return HttpResponse("Hello, a django view.")
```

In the app/urls.py I put

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^index$', views.index, name = 'index'),
]
```

added the following to project/urls.py

```
urlpattrens = [
    url(r'^home/', include('app.urls')),
    # below is admin url created with startproject
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls)),
]
```

lastly I turn DEBUT=False in project/settings.py, and added ip to ALLOWED_HOSTS

After `python manage.py runserver ip:8080` , ip:8080/home/index, and ip:8080/admin are all available.

Next I tried restart apache2, went to mysite.com/admin and mysite.com/home/index

both got

```
404
Not Found The requested URL /admin was not found on this server.
```

I guess the mod_wsgi is not working.

The httpd.conf looks like

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so

WSGIScriptAlias / /usr/local/django/virenv/Personal/mysite.com/project/wsgi.py process-group=mysite.com
WSGIPythonHome /usr/local/django/virenv
WSGIDaemonProcess mysite.com python-home=/usr/local/django/virenv python-path=/usr/local/django/virenv/Personal/mysite.com
WSGIProcessGroup mysite.com
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

<Directory /usr/local/django/virenv/Personal/mysite.com/project>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/local/django/virenv/Personal/mysite.com/>
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
     Require all granted
     Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -Includes
</Directory>
```

000-default.conf looks like

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /usr/local/django/virenv/Personal/mysite.com
        <Directory /usr/local/django/virenv/Personal/mysite.com>
            AllowOverride All
            Options +FollowSymLinks
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I use ubuntu 16 lts with apache2.4, django 1.10

every directory and file along this path

```
/usr/local/django/virenv/Personal/mysite.com/*
```

is set to `chmod a+x` and `chmod a+r`

Any guesses or solution?

EDIT: by the way, in wsgi.py

```
import os
import sys # added from other stack overflow answers
import django.core.handlers.wsgi as WSGIhand # added from other posts
os.environ.["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "project.settings"

application = WSGIhand.WSGIHandler()
```

Comment: You should not set ``DocumentRoot`` to be where your application code is. If you stuff up something in Apache configuration it means people could download your source code including sensitive information in your Django settings file.

Comment: Why do you have all your application configuration in httpd.conf? Except for ``LoadModule``, it should be inside of the ``VirtualHost`` definition. Also drop ``WSGIPythonHome`` as not strictly needed since using daemon mode.

Comment: And your wsgi.py file isn't what Django would generate for you when starting a project, why change it? Looks to be based on what would be used for much older Django version.